# How to register custom environment with OpenAI's gym package to use make_vec_env() in SB3 (for multiprocessing)?

Tags: python, openai-gym, stable-baselines

Goal: In Stable Baselines 3, I want to be able to run multiple workers on my environment in parallel (multiprocessing) to train my model.

Method: As shown in this [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/Stable-Baselines-Team/rl-colab-notebooks/blob/sb3/multiprocessing_rl.ipynb#scrollTo=TgjfyOTPVxG6), I believe I just need to run the below line of code:

> vec_env = make_vec_env(env_id, n_envs=num_cpu)

However, I have a custom environment, which doesn't have an env_id. So, when I run it just like "make_vec_env(MyEnvironment(), n_envs=3)", I get an error saying that my environment isn't callable. There seems to be a general lack of documentation around this, but from what I gather from [this thread](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/993), I need to register my custom environment with Gym so that I can call on it with the make_vec_env() function.

My first question: Is there any other way to run multiple workers on a custom environment? If not...

My second question: How do I register my custom environment with Gym?

Again, documentation seems somewhat lacking. I have found these [one](https://saashanair.com/blog/blog-posts/custom-environments-in-openai-gym#ec261e65cda94ff69fe69cfc8d0e97bf), [two](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/content/environment_creation/), [three](https://towardsdatascience.com/beginners-guide-to-custom-environments-in-openai-s-gym-989371673952#:%7E:text=As%20long%20as%20you%20have%20the%20corresponding%20environment,gym-basic%2C%20and%20use%20pip%3A%20pip%20install%20-e%20gym-basic) posts which outline the steps. However, I don't understand - can I just place this folder anywhere I want? How does Gym know where to find it? Why do I need two **init**.py files?

Any guidance whatsoever would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by registering your custom env, let's call it myEnv. Assuming you pass a previously defined dataframe to the constructor of your class, it looks like this:

```
class myEnv:
    def __init__(self, myFancyDF: pd.DataFrame):
        ...
    
    ...
```

You can do that by having this after the definition in the same code:

```
myEnv_id = 'optionalSpaceName/myEnv-v0' # It is best practice to have a space name and version number.

gym.envs.registration.register(
    id=myEnv_id,
    entry_point=myEnv,
    max_episode_steps=20000, # Customize to your needs.
    reward_threshold=500 # Customize to your needs.
)
```

Now you can create a vector env with:

```
vec_env = make_vec_env(myEnv_id, n_envs=100, seed=0, env_kwargs={"myFancyDF": myFancyDF})
```